# Problem extending class with javascript object prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, function-prototypes

I have got this problem... B is a base class, and A is a derived class... Event though A is derived from B, various objects of A points to the same object of B.

I know i have assigned an object of B to the prototype of A to make A child of B.

But different objects of A, they should have different address space to hold the variables, right? Can you anyone correct this?

```
    function B(){

        this.obj = {};
    }

    function A(){

    }

    A.prototype = new B();

    var a = new A();
    var b = new A();
    var c = new A();

    console.log(a.obj == b.obj); //prints true
    console.log(a.obj === b.obj); //prints true

    a.obj.name = "stackoverflow";
    console.log(b.obj.name); //prints stackoverflow
```

What change should I make in this code so that gives me following result.

```
a.obj === b.obj  //must be false

a instanceof A;  //must be true
a instanceof B;  //must be true
```

Comment: What exactly is it you're asking? What are the problems with the code you've posted or the difference in expected behavior?

Comment: Please have a look, I have corrected the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's why you shouldn't have mutable values (particularly objects or arrays) on a prototype - the same value will be shared across all object instances and can be changed in any of them. Here you can avoid the problem by using [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) that won't call the constructor of `B` when creating the prototype:

```
A.prototype = Object.create(B.prototype);
```

Constructor of `A` should then call the constructor of `B` for each new object:

```
function A() {
  B.call(this);
}
```

For browsers that don't support `Object.create()` you can emulate it as mentioned on http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html.

Answer (score 2):

Values are assigned by reference, and since all instances of A use the same instance of B as their prototype, they all refer to the same 'B'.

So this is exactly what's expected here. One way to solve this, is to add (for instance) a 'initialize' method the B 'class', which you could then call from within the A constructor.

You can also *not* use 'new B()' to define the prototype, and use Object.create instead. Object.create does not call B's constructor, but you can then call the parent constructor from A.

```
function A() {
   B.call(this);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, my second requirement doesn't work here... That is, 
a instanceof B == true

Answer (score 1):

This is a part of prototypes in Javascript, I suggest you read [this excellent thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892595/javascript-prototype-inheritance).