# What does it mean to assign a constructor to something?

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I see something like this which I quite don't understand:

```
// ...

that.constructor = ...

//...
```

I though the constructor property was not supposed to be something to assign something to, but a property that returned that which the object was an instance of. I thought that `.constructor` was a property like `.length` for strings that returns data and is not perferable to be changed. Is this true?

Comment: Constructors are typically (in languages) the code that gets called when the object is created. There are caveats in JS. See: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.constructors

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: prototype inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892595/javascript-prototype-inheritance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an ECMAScript function object is created, it is given a public *prototype* property that is a plain object, just in case the function is used as a constructor. The prototype object is given a public *constructor* property that is a reference to the function. Instances created from the constructor will inherit the prototype's constructor property (unless it is shaddowed by a constructor property on the instance or higher up its *prototype* chain).

The constructor property may be re-assigned, usually because the original prototype object is replaced with some other object. The constructor property can be set to anything, therefore it is not seen as particularly useful.

In regard to the prototye property of host objects (if they have one at all), be aware that they can do whatever they like (including throwing errors if you try to set or even access them).

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the constructor of all javascript object instances. There's a neat example in mozilla's documentation:

```
function Type(){};
var types = [
    new Array,  [],
    new Boolean,    true,
    new Date,
    new Error,
    new Function,   function(){},
    Math,   
    new Number, 1,
    new Object, {},
    new RegExp, /(?:)/,
    new String, "test"
];
for(var i = 0; i < types.length; i++){
    types[i].constructor = Type;
    types[i] = [types[i].constructor, types[i] instanceof Type, types[i].toString()];
};
alert(types.join("\n"));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the above are **built-in** ECMAScript objects, which are special and behave differently to other native objects (i.e. those created using script but not host objects).

Comment: But what's the point of setting `contructor` to anything?? Isn't it set by default?

Comment: I think the answer @RobG gave gives a better description of why you would consider changing it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the constructor will return the function which created the object prototype.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_constructor_boolean.asp

For instance, like w3schools says:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var bool=new Boolean();
document.write(bool.constructor);
</script>
```

Will return:

```
function Boolean() { [native code] }
```

I've never used it, but I figured it was for debug purposes.

Comment: Just an FYI, but quoting `w3schools`, while not categorically wrong, will almost always cause recriminations on SO. See: http://w3fools.com.