# Javascript constructors with parameters

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototypal-inheritance

In trying to understand javascript constructors, I have been looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892595/javascript-prototypal-inheritance).

It seemed to me that I understood it reasonably, but, ironically, when I tried to run similar code, it did not work for me at all.

This is my code

```
function Car(name) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Year = 1999;
}

Car.prototype.Drive = function() {
    document.write("My name is '" + this.Name + "' and my year is '" + this.Year + "'. <br />");
};

SuperCar = function () { };
SuperCar.prototype = new Car();

function SuperCar(name) {
    Car.call(this, name);
}

var MyCar = new Car("mycar");
var MySuperCar = new SuperCar("my super car");

MyCar.Drive();
MySuperCar.Drive();
```

First of all, this line

```
SuperCar = function () { };
```

was necessary for it to run at all. If I leave it out, I the error "SuperCar is undefined" at this line.

```
SuperCar.prototype = new Car();
```

I don't really understand why declaring SuperCar as an empty function was necessary.

Secondly, when I do run the code I get this result

```
My name is 'mycar' and my year is '1999'. 
My name is 'undefined' and my year is '1999'.
```

Apparently, for MySuperCar, the SuperCar(name) function is never called, but the Car() is.

Adding this line does not help

```
SuperCar.prototype.constructor = SuperCar;
```

Neither does this

```
SuperCar.prototype.constructor = function(name) {
    Car.call(this, name);
};
```

(I have been running the code inside a script-tag on IE 9 and Chrome 22)

How should I properly define a SuperCar constructor taking a name parameter? Or, put it another way, how can I make the new SuperCar("my super car") call behave the way I expected (setting the name to "my super car")?

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Gs4qu/ You might stay away from `document.write` in general, I would suggest `document.body.innerHTML = "blah blah blah<br>";` instead, or DOM methods.

Comment: It's also working if I comment out the function variable you're asking about: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Gs4qu/1/ Right below that you've got `function SuperCar(name){...}` declared, and hoisting puts it at the top of the scope. So unless for some time that function didn't exist or was originally a variable function or function variable (who can tell the difference?), I don't see why that would be a problem. I'm talking about Chrome here, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not really create an instance of `Car` as the prototype, but only create an object that inherits from `Car.prototype`. For the details, see [What is the reason to use the 'new' keyword at Derived.prototype = new Base](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572). Instead, use

```
SuperCar.prototype = Object.create(Car.prototype);
```

---

Your problem is that your `SuperCar`s are created by the empty function - which returns an object without any properties. Yet, they inherit from `new Car()`, whose `name` is `undefined`. This happened in your fiddle because the *function declaration* (beginning with the `function` keyword, check out [this explanation](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#expr-vs-decl)) is hoisted (available everywhere in the scope) and overwritten by the line

```
SuperCar = function () { };
```

so that your `SuperCar` constructor does not call the `Car` constructor any more. [Fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gs4qu/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You did not need the empty function. You made an empty `SuperCar` function and then set its prototype, but then over-wrote it with a *new* definition of `SuperCar`.

```
function SuperCar() {}
SuperCar.prototype = new Car();

function SuperCar() {} // original SuperCar overwritten
```

Comment: No, you do not need to set the `constructor` property to a new instance.

Comment: And no, the second function declaration does not overwrite the first one as well.

Comment: @Bergi But it was definitively that empty function that did it because when I take it out it works fine.

Comment: Yes, but it was the function *expression* above the original function declaration - see my answer