# Structuring my jquery/javascript properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

These days I find myself putting a lot of my code in the `$(document).ready()` which does not seem clean to me. For example, if I am creating something that will query my database via ajax and return it and append it to my list i would do something like this:

```
$(function(){
   //Initialize my DOM elements
   $MyList = $("#MyList"),
   $MyButton = $("#MyButton");

   //Add my Click event
   $MyButton.click(function(){
      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: "/lists/getmylist",
         contentType: "application/json",
         success: function(results){
            //Parse my results and append them using my favorite templating helper
            var jsonResults = $.parseJSON(result);
            $MyList.mustache("my-template", jsonResults);
         }
      });
   })
});
```

Now I know this is a small example but it starts to get really big and messy when I have multiple click events, ajax requests etc.  It all ends up going in my document ready.  I know that I can possibly put all my ajax requests in an external javascript file to help make it cleaner, but is this architecture in general ok?  just seems like its really messy.  I have seen others use plugin architectures or init functions. I usually have this document ready at the bottom of all my pages and just throw in whatever is necessary to make my page work correctly. Is this a good way to structure my js?

Comment: I can migrate this over to our Code Review beta site if you'd like. You might get better answers over there. @ reply me if you'd like that.

Answer (score 4):

I think the addition of some Model objects and general object oriented programming principals might go a long way here. If you break your your data fetching and storing out into model classes it should help a lot.

Here are some links that should get you started thinking about OO with Javascript.

[Writing Object-Oriented JavaScript](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5608/Writing-Object-Oriented-JavaScript-Part-1)

[Javascript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)

[Javascript: prototypal inheritance](http://beej.us/blog/data/javascript-prototypes-inheritance/)
[Javascript: prototypal inheritance 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892595/javascript-prototypal-inheritance)

Another thing that might help out would be to break the Javascript into multiple files. One for global scripts that might be included via a header that attaches to all your pages and a script for each of your pages that requires it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) ( or one of the other [frameworks](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/) ) could be part of the rescue you are looking for.

I found Backbone immensely helpful organising some inherited spaghetti. Your starting point might be to transition your massive document ready into a backbone view (or multiples of)

Organise your scripts by separating out the views, collections, models into individual files then bundle and minify them together into a single file so the browser only needs to make one request instead of many.

ASP.NET MVC4 can do the [bundling](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) for you, it also works similarly on MVC3

This is just a example of simple starting point, there are more advanced techniques (eg. AMD, require.js) to reduce the script size per page, but with caching and gzip I find that the single everything script bundle is fine for a lot of cases.

As for your example, here's a possible backbone implementation

Remember to namespace out your code...

```
var app = app || {};

$(function ($) {

// depending on your server setup you might be able to just override the url
// and get away with what you want. Otherwise you might look into overriding
// the save/fetch or sync methods of the collection
app.MyListCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/lists/getmylist'

});


app.MyListView = Backbone.View.extend({

//bind the view to the existing element in the HTML.
    el: '#MyList',

    // your mustache template 
    template:$('#list-template').html(),

    // hook up your event handlers to page components
//(within the context of your el)
    events: {
        'click #MyButton': 'onMyButtonClick'
    },

    //called on object creation.
    initialize: function () {

//you could create a collection here or pass it into the init function
        this.collection = new app.MyListCollection();

        //when the collection is changes, call the render method
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    },
    // render is named by convention, but its where you would "redraw" your view and apply your template
    render: function () {

    this.$el.html(
        Mustache.render(
            this.template(this.collection.toJSON())));

        return this;
    },

    //your click handler
    onMyButtonClick: function(e){
        this.collection.fetch();
    }

});
});
```

use your doc ready to spin up whatever backbone functionality you need
and use it bootstrap your javascript with any server side data that you may have.

```
$(function () {

// create an instance of your view
new app.MyListView();

//example bootstrap using razor
app.title = @Model.Title;
});
```