# Referring to the window object from within a prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

So, I'm trying to get some traction with prototypes in JavaScript, and I started by trying something basically like the second example in
[Understanding prototypal inheritance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892595/javascript-prototypal-inheritance).
Currently, I have a bunch of functions that, were I writing in C++, would certainly like to inherit from a parent class; imagine a bunch of functions like

```
function specificDevice(){
     this.codeNumber = 'abc123';
     this.wrapperDiv = window.parameters.dashboardDiv;
}
```

I have a whole pile of these functions, and everything worked fine - but the code was kind of silly, since they all shared a lot of members cut and pasted from one to the next.  So, per the link above, I did something like

```
function generalDevice(){
     this.codeNumber = 'abc123';
}

specificDevice.prototype = new generalDevice();

function specificDevice(){
     this.wrapperDiv = window.parameters.dashboardDiv;

     //just to check if this does what I think it does:
     alert(this.codeNumber);
     alert(this.wrapperDiv);
}
```

And when I make a new instance of `specificDevice`, the alerts spat out exactly what I expected - 'abc123', and whatever I previously defined as `window.parameters.dashboardDiv` - perfect!  But then, I tried to do what I figured would be the exactly analogous thing on the member variable being pulled from the `window` object; the above now becomes:

```
function generalDevice(){
     this.codeNumber = 'abc123';
     this.wrapperDiv = window.parameters.dashboardDiv;
}

specificDevice.prototype = new generalDevice();

function specificDevice(){
     alert(this.wrapperDiv)
}
```

Disaster - the script falls over with a

```
'Cannot read property "dashboardDiv" of undefined'.
```

I'm hoping the problem is obvious to the experts - how come I can make an object that happily recognizes my `window.parameters` as a thing, but that object's prototype thinks `window.parameters` doesn't exist??  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you use `window` in the first place? Why don't you use just `parameters`? JavaScript will resolve the scope (assuming it's a unique variable name)

Comment: Seems to be a simple matter of execution order. You're presumably invoking `generalDevice()` before you've defined `window.parameters`. This may be happening while you're defining the `.prototype` of `specificDevice`. You can create an inherited object without invoking the constructor that holds the prototype by using `Object.create`. So... `specificDevice.prototype = Object.create(generalDevice.prototype);`

Comment: @elclanrs : sure, but the same problem persists.

Comment: @amnotiam : ...yes, I think you're right!  The undefined window.parameters thing goes away when I do it your way; unfortunately it's then replaced with a different problem (specificDevice then can't fetch *anything* from the generalDevice prototype) - but I think that's a different problem, seeing as what you said about generalDevice getting called immediately is correct.  Thanks very much!

Comment: You're welcome. And to your new issue, I would guess that you may be invoking `specificDevice` before you've assigned its new `.prototype` object.

Comment: @amnotiam - I didn't think so, but I'm not going to insist; the problem goes away however, if I do like the mozilla folks under their Object.create example, and do generalDevice.call(this) at the top of specificDevice - then everything is perfect.  Thanks for pointing out Object.create()!

Comment: @user1807834: That's absolutely correct. I failed to notice that you weren't applying the `generalDevice` constructor logic to the `specificDevice` object. I was too focused on the prototype. The Mozilla solution is correct.

Comment: Object.create should also work, without .call, if you simply move codeNumber and wrapperDiv to generalDevice.prototype (since that's what you're extending if you use the code provided by @amnotiam).