# Classical Inheritance implement in javascript

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is inherit the `id` and `name` from the `TField` and override the `render` function of the `TField`. I want to know if this is the stardard way to implement inheritance in JavaScript.

```
var TField=function(jData)
{
   this.id=jData.id;
   this.name=jData.name;
   this.attributes=jData.attributes;
   this.render=function(){
      alert('TField render.');
   };
};

var TChildField=function(jData)
{
    var t= new TField(jData);
    t.render=function(){
       alert('TChildField render.');
    }
    return t;
}

var tobj={id:"1",name:"test",attribute:{}};


var c= new TChildField(tobj);
alert(c.id);
alert(c.name);
```

Comment: I suggest you to have a look to some Javascript resources:
- http://eloquentjavascript.net/  (chapter 8 in particular)
- http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: Good, It definetely what I need. Any idea about the code . Is there anything wrong with it ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it probably is a good idea to remove the `render` definition from the constructor and add it to the prototype directly with:

```
TField.prototype.render=function(){
      alert('TField render.');
};
```

Secondly, to set up inheritance of the constructor, use:

```
var TChildField=function(jData)
{
    TField.call(this,jData)
}
```

Then, link the the  two prototypes

```
TChildField.prototype=Object.create(TField.prototype)
```

Finally, overwrite `render()` for `TChildField`

```
TChildField.prototype.render=function(){
      alert('TChildField render.');
};


var TField=function(jData)
{
   this.id=jData.id;
   this.name=jData.name;
   this.attributes=jData.attributes;

};

TField.prototype.render=function(){
      alert('TField render.');
};

var TChildField=function(jData)
{
    TField.call(this,jData)
}

var tobj={id:"1",name:"test",attribute:{}};
TChildField.prototype=Object.create(TField.prototype)
TChildField.prototype.render=function(){
      alert('TChildField render.');
};
var c= new TChildField(tobj);
alert(c.id);
alert(c.name);
```

Comment: @GrzegorzKaczan: Well, I copied the prototype of the parent class to the child class. This makes it scalable, since then I can add more functions and they will be automatically inherited.

Comment: I found this is the way the w3cschool javascript tutorial recommended.

Comment: Hi, @Manishearth, Could I put the code `TChildField.prototype.render=function(){..};` inside the `var TChildField=function(jData){...};` ?

Comment: @Joe.wang: No, don't do that. Not sure if you _can_, but it may lead to unexpected results. And it will get overwritten when we link the prototypes anyway.

Comment: @Manishearth , I just want all the code is closed in the class definiton just like the classical inheritance in the oop language like `c#` or `java`.

Comment: @Joe.wang: This isn't Java/C#. Prototypal inheritance is different, it's better if you define your functions separately. The var `TField=function(...` is _not_ a class definition, it's a _constructor_ definition. Would you stuff all your method definitions in a constructor in Java? Probably not ;-)

Comment: The problem of this way I can see is `TChildField.prototype.render=function(){..};` can't use the parameter of the constuctor definition directly. I doubted it can only utilize the public field .like `this.id` , `this.name` etc. so . that will cause many public field or global field exist without need.

Comment: @Joe.wang: I don't understand what you're saying. It _can_ access `this.id`, etc. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: @Manishearth I mean can I use the `jData` in the function `TChildField.prototype.render=function(){..};`?  I don't want it be the public field .

Comment: @Manishearth I know It can access the public property like `this.id`, etc.

Comment: @Joe.wang: Well, no. What's wrong with making it a property of the object? 

Thing is, you won't have a proper inheritance _and_ have private data like this. The only way out is to just define the two classes separately, and don't link them in any way.

Comment: @Manishearth I can see the way of defining two classes probably equal with most of the code is not good idea .. It will against OOP and DRY.

Comment: @joe well, data hiding never really was necessary in JS. It's not againt oop, oop doesn't _have_ to have private members.

Comment: But yeah, defining two classes is against dry. Which is why I didn't answer with that :)

Answer (score 1):

This is more like decorator pattern inheritance. But its working as you expected, just call `c.render()`. 
To do classical prototypal inheritance, just assign `TField` to be prototype of `TChildField`.
Look at [Understanding prototypal inheritance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892595/javascript-prototypal-inheritance)