# Javascript: How do you enter in unknown variables?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game where the player can pick 3 different characters. However I am running into a glaring problem, that being, when I create a function (like a attack function), it is linked to only 1 specific character.

I would rather have my code be written where when the person picks their character, all can use the same attack skill without me having to write 3 different ones. Also, the attack skills are linked to a button, so it must be diverse.

I can't have a **designated** attack button for X player. So how do I make my code so it can add all characters instead of just 1 specified character?

**Example:** Looking at my function below for the **strike** attack. I can set it to dwarf & angel which is fine. However what if the player picks a ELF character instead? Then the function will not work because it believes the character is a dwarf, fighting a angel. How can I fix this?

```
New=Object.create;

actor = {
    primaryStats: function (level, hp, hpcap, balance, balancecap, exp){
        this.level = level;
        this.hp = hp;
        this.hpcap = hpcap;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.balancecap = balancecap;
        this.exp = exp;
},

player = New (actor),
monster = New (actor),

dwarf = New(player),
human = New(player),
elf = New(player),

angel = New(monster),
demon = New(monster),
dragon = New(monster);

//ATTACK SKILL ONE
dom.el("strike").onclick = function strike() {

    playerHitCalc(dwarf, angel);
    };   

    playerHitCalc = function(character, boss){
        roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * character.accuracy + 1);
        if (roll > boss.agility){
            var hit = true;
        }
        else {
            hit = false;
            logMessage(boss.ID + " " + "has evaded your attack!")
        }
        playerDamCalc = function(){
            if (hit == true){ //If you score a successful hit
                var damage = Math.floor(Math.random() * character.strength + 1);
                var totalDamage = damage - boss.armor; // Subtract Damage from Bosses Armor
                if(totalDamage <= 0)totalDamage += boss.armor; // Add boss armor to prevent Negative Numbers
                boss.hp -= totalDamage; // Subtract bosses HP from damage.
                character.exp += totalDamage * 0.25; // Gain 1 exp point per 4 damage done
                dom.setText("bosshealthcounter", boss.hp) // Update Bosses Health
                logMessage("You hit " + boss.ID + " for " + totalDamage + " damage!");
            }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892595/understanding-prototypal-inheritance-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use data attributes to link a dom element to particular characters. For example -

```
 <button class="attack-btn" data-attacker="dwarf" data-target="angel">Attack</button>
```

Then in the on click handler, you can extract that particular element's attributes **attacker** and **target** instead of hardcoding the values.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you are doing is creating `Player` and `Monster` from `Actor` and then specific player class from `Player` and the same for monster.

Problem lies in that now you have a specific handle for each type of player and each type of monster.

If we would want to edit current code, you would have to add `currentPlayer` and `currentMonster` variables that you would make equal to the `Player` and `Monster` you want to fight. Then you could avoid referencing specific `player` and specific `monster` and just use

`playerHitCalc(currentPlayer, currentMonster);`

But I would suggest changing things a little bit and [create objects in a little different way.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function)