# Manage JS inheritance failure

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I am new to Object Orientated Programming, please have in mind. I have understood how the first part shown here works (it does):

```
function Car() {

    var  __registration;

    var setReg = function(val) {
         __registration= val;
    }

    var getReg= function() {
        return  __registration;
    }


    return {
        setReg: setReg ,
        getReg: getReg

    }

}

var myCar = new Car();
myCar.setReg("LSKM5215");
alert(myCar.getReg() );   //ALERTS LSKM5215
```

But when trying to manage inheritance  on this way of Object Orientated Programming, it just fails once and again:

```
function Extras(){

    var  __sound;

    var setSound= function(val) {
         __sound= val;
    }

    var getSound= function() {
        return  __sound;
    }


    return {
        setSound: setSound,
        getSound: getSound

    }

}

Extras.prototype = new Car();

myCar.setSound("SUPERB SOUNDSYSTEM 2.2");    //TypeError: myCar.setSound is not a function
```

How could I create inheritance on this case? To make Car() get the private variables about the *"soundsystem extras"*?

Very grateful.

Comment: You never assign anything to myCar in the second example

Comment: You never use `Extras`.

Comment: you not need `return`, when plan use function as constructor

Comment: You are not using constructor functions but factory functions.  myCar does not inherit anything from either Car or Extras functions.

Comment: in your case - `myCar` is object _base_ class, you add additional method in extras, that should be derived, so how object of base class can know about new method in derived?

Comment: So @SergiuParaschiv, I need to first assign new Extras() to my newCar I understand? I'll try

Comment: If you're using Node or a transpiler like Babel (writing react or Angular 2 for instance) you should just use `class`.

Comment: I suggest you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892595/understanding-prototypal-inheritance-in-javascript It's far more in-depth than any answer we could duplicate here.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum look at the transpiled code and you'll find there's nothing magic about it, it's still basic prototype based inheritance.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv, even when I assign to myCar = new Extras(), does not work (it even does not recognise now the myCar.setReg() as a function). Could you explain me the correct way to solve this?

Comment: Ok @SergiuParaschiv I'll take a look.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cuktaqky/1/

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv you know that, I know that, but for someone learning it would be great to learn it the simple way first and only then get into prototypical inheritance. Syntax matters IMO :)

Comment: In the long run I think learning it "low-level" _is_ the simple way.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv so the problem was just on the return I guess from your example. If I take out the return, is this still a private way of OOP? All was right except for that final return...

Comment: @gas1986 Not quite.  Also pay attention to the property functions - `var functionName` is not the same as `this.functionName`

Comment: @Archer you are right. By this way, is this still a private way of OOP? That's the first way I learned OOP, as a non-private way of programming. Is this getting back to the public method?

Comment: You originally mixed public and private by having private property functions and passing references in the return value.  You can keep private functions private by simply not specifying `this` when creating them, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, it is more or less clear. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: As a sidenote, Javascript isn't traditionally OOP, so you're better off using Typescript to learn about OOP principles, if that's what you're aiming for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not need `return` when plan use function as constructor.

in derived class you should call base constructor with needed parameters.

in derived class assign proptotype based on base prototype.

Something like this:

```js
function Car() {

  var __registration;

  this.setReg = function(val) {
    __registration = val;
  }

  this.getReg = function() {
    return __registration;
  }

}

function Extras() {
  Car.call(this);
  var __sound;

  this.setSound = function(val) {
    __sound = val;
  }

  this.getSound = function() {
    return __sound;
  }

}

Extras.prototype = Object.create(Car.prototype);

myExtras = new Extras();
myExtras.setReg("LSKM5215");
myExtras.setSound("SUPERB SOUNDSYSTEM 2.2");

document.write("<div>Extras: reg - ", myExtras.getReg(), '</div>');
document.write("<div>Extras: sound - ", myExtras.getSound(), '</div>');
```

And for ES2015 you can use [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

```js
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  get area() {
    return this.calcArea();
  }

  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}

class Car {

  constructor() {
    this.__registration = undefined;
  }

  set Reg(val) {
    this.__registration = val;
  }

  get Reg() {
    return this.__registration;
  }

}

class Extras extends Car {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.__sound = undefined;
  }

  set Sound(val) {
    this.__sound = val;
  }

  get Sound() {
    return this.__sound;
  }

}

myExtras = new Extras();
myExtras.Reg = ("LSKM5215");
myExtras.Sound = ("SUPERB SOUNDSYSTEM 2.2");

document.write("<div>Extras: reg - ", myExtras.Reg, '</div>');
document.write("<div>Extras: sound - ", myExtras.Sound, '</div>');
```